# pip install from github repository with optional dependency

Tags: python, git, pip

I am installing python packages from GiTHub repository via ssh like following.

```
pip install pandas@git+ssh://git@github.com/pandas-dev/pandas.git@main
```

In addition to this, I want to install test dependencies of packages.
I know that I can install package from PYPI server with following,

```bash
pip install pandas[test]
```

but I want to install directory from GitHub via SSH.

I couldn't find an option for such additional dependency in a [document](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/vcs-support/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using following command:

```bash
pip install "pandas[test] @ git+https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas@main"
```